# how can I copy a range of cells from one worksheet to other 24-worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy a certain range of cells in other 18 worksheets.  In the below code I have mentioned "student#1", but there are altogether total 24 sheets with .  Code I have written is like this:

```
Sub copyrange()
Sheets("stn-1questions").Range("d1:f26").Copy Sheets("student#1").Range("d10")
End Sub
```

Would appreciate if someone can help me

Comment: use [loop](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html)

Comment: You should the accept the answer you liked.  Click the outline tick against the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
Sub main()
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSheet As String
For i = 1 To 18
    strSheet = "student#" & Strings.Trim(Str(i))
    Call Sheets("stn-1questions").Range("d1:f26").Copy(Sheets(strSheet).Range("d10"))
Next i
End Sub
```

It will loop through each sheet and copy the value in its appropriate location

Comment: np, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This will loop through each sheet in your macro workbook and copy the range to each sheet containing "student#".

```
Sub copyrange()
    Dim s As Worksheet

    ' Loop through all sheets in the workbook
    For Each s In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        ' If the current sheet has the word "student#" in its name
        If InStr(s.Name, "student#") Then
            ' Copy the range D1:F26 to the current sheet
            Sheets("stn-1questions").Range("D1:F26").Copy s.Range("D10")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```